# Get all folders which contain files using Batch command

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Good day everyone!  I have a parent folder that contains millions of files and directories and subdirectories. I want to know all the folders which contain files and  generate all those folder names in a text file.
I have tried playing with the below batch command

```
dir /A:-D /b /s > files.txt
```

Output

```
temp/user/clientA/XML/ITCJXQ 1001111/1001111.xml
temp/user/clientA/XML/ITCJXQ 1001111/1001111.pdf
temp/user/clientA/XML/ITCJXQ 1001111/1001111.html
temp/user/clientA/XML/ITCJXQ 1002345/1002345.xml
temp/user/clientA/XML/ITCJXQ 1002345/1002345.pdf
temp/user/clientA/XML/ITCJXQ 1002345/1002345.html
```

What I expect is to see

```
temp/user/clientA/XML/ITCJXQ 1001111/
temp/user/clientA/XML/ITCJXQ 1002345/
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! This question is about how to use Windows/cmd/DOS, so it belongs on our sister site, [su]. Please read [their tour](https://superuser.com/tour), and learn how to use the code formatting button in the question editor. Thanks!

Comment: @jpaugh, I will disagree that it belongs on Super User. This is code that goes into a batch file which makes it a programming question.

Comment: I have never seen the `DIR` command output with forward slashes.  Would like to know how you were able to get that output.

Comment: As a first step, though, `/A:-D` is wrong (see output from `DIR /?` for help). The command is either `/AD` (for directories only) or `/A-D` (for files only). However, the first form lists _all_ directories, not just those containing files. Look at `FOR /?` -- specifically `FOR /R` to walk the directory tree -- where you can then test for the presence of files.

Comment: @TripeHound, the form `/A:-D` (or `/A:D`) is not wrong, the colon is just optional...

Comment: @aschipfl Doh! You learn something every day (I can now even see it in the `DIR/?` text I pointed the OP to!) and I've been using PCs since at least DOS 3. OP: Ignore the first bit; I'm wrong!

Comment: @squashman apologies, yes you're correct. It should have been backslash instead of "/". I typed that manually hence the "/".
@TripeHound I was initially trying to get all the files from the folders and wants them to be listed in a file. However, i think it would have been efficient for my task to retrieve just the non-null folders instead. Will check `FOR /R` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took this from some code I use at the end of the day to check if all my automation folders are not empty.  Essentially the FOR command is getting a list of directories.  The command executed inside the for command checks if the folder has files in it.

```
@echo off
FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('dir /ad /b /s') DO (
    >nul 2>nul dir /a-d /b "%%~G\*" && echo %%G>>"FolderNotEmpty.txt"
)
```